# How to convert a flat string to array not having spaces?

Tags: php

I can convert a string `'html php js'` to array using `explode`, such as

```
$string = 'html php js';
$output_array = explode(' ', $string);
```

and it works fine. But how to convert a string that has no spaces?

```
$string = 'html';

// *** outputs as ['h','t','m','l']
```

and that the output has to be an array of strings.

Comment: See: [str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the str_split function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php